# What is the early modern equivalent of ' I think '

Tags: translation, early-modern-english

Would the term 'I think' be used in this era?
I'm looking at translation for a piece of art, 
I'm wanting to translate flippant/meaningless language from today (things people say drunk, tweets etc.) into early modern english- or the type of language used in shakespeare.
If anyone has any knowledge in this field I would greatly appreciate your help!!

Comment: Used in what particular context? Do you have any possible ideas? Could you supply a whole sentence?

Comment: "I think" could be used in a few different contexts. _I think I'll have a salad tonight. I think about Martha all the time. Joe was wrong about that, I think._ And what time frame do you mean when you refer to the "early modern" era? If you edit your question and address such details, people might be able to answer your question. As it stands now, I think it might be hard to supply any kind of answer.

Comment: I suspect you are thinking about the archaic word _methinks_.

Comment: See also _meseems_. _Seem_ and _think_ useta mean more or less the same thing, and both had dative subject constructions: _Methinks (that) `S`_ and _Meseems (that) `S`_. But in modern English they've gone separate ways; _think_ is now transitive with an experiencer or agent subject, the thinker. _Seem_, on the other hand, has promoted the experience to subject while making the experiencer optional. Viz, _I think the Hawks are likely to win_ vs _It seems the Hawks are likely to win_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Dative *subject* constructions? I have always parsed both as impersonal, translatable into PDE as "it seems to me."

Comment: I'm doing an art project, in which I'm translating things my friend said drunk into early modern english- for instance 'Vince thinks I want to bone' any help would be appreciated, i think the outcome will be interesting.

Comment: The experiencer of the thinking or seeming is first person. It's expressed as a dative _to_ phrase _seems to me_, which is historically the fate of the _me_ in _meseems_. In _methinks_ the same construction became a more-or-less volitional subject in _I think_, but it's also the experiencer of the mentation. Both started out as dative subjects (Cf German _Es gibt mir keine Angst_ 'I don't have any worries', lit 'It gives to me no worry').

Comment: @J.R. The various epochs of Western History are usually considered as follows. Prior to the foundation of the Holy Roman Empire is generally termed 'Ancient history'. From about 800AD to the Norman Conquest is 'Early Medieval'. From then to the Reformation (early 1500s) is 'Late Medieval'. 'EARLY MODERN' usually covers the period between the Reformation and the French Revolution (1789). In England that means the Elizabethan, the Interregnum, the religious questions of the 17th century, and the early beginnings of the Industrial Revolution in the 18th. 1789 *et seq* is thought of as 'Modern'.

Comment: @WS2 - I've seen that before; my comment was simply meant to coax the O.P. to include that tidbit, in order to improve the question (which seems to have worked, based on the subsequent edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes (a somewhat-serious but humorous "translation" of some modern text into Elizabethan English), you'll want to emphasize the phrasing differences between the two forms.

So, for times when you need to translate "I think", you would use the well-understood but archaic word **methinks**, and for times when you need to translate the third person (e.g. "Vince thinks"), you would use the archaic phrase "**doth think**", which while uncommon in Shakespeare does [indeed](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=5&SC=1&IdPlay=26#207649) [appear](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=1&SC=6&IdPlay=7#137312).

> Zounds! Vince doth think that my loins burn!

Comment: One cannot possibly find a better example of *Early Modern English* than the King James I version of the bible.